# Google Dialogflow API v2 Explorer access_token field

Tags: google-api, dialogflow-es, google-apis-explorer

Please forgive me, I am fairly new to the Dialogflow Api (v2.)

I am starting off with testing these API calls using the [Google API Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/get) utility on the right side of the page.

My question is specifically about the **"access_token"** field:

Is this supposed to be the **JSON authentication file** that I downloaded from the Google Cloud Console when I created a new service account?

If not, then where do I find the **specific resource** I am actually supposed to pass into this field?

*Side note: I read in the support section: "Google engineers monitor and answer questions about the Google API Explorer on Stack Overflow using the tag google-apis-explorer." **Thank you all in advance for your service/help in this topic!***

Answer (score 1):

The `access_token` field is a higher-level field used across the API by some tooling. In some manual client libraries, you might need to use it, but for the API Explorer utility and for most use-cases, you can ignore it. This is true of most (maybe all) fields under the "Show standard parameters" zippy.

The documentation on the left side should explain the relevant fields you need to fill in to successfully complete a request. Keep in mind that even some of these fields are optional; you can leave them blank if they are not relevant to your goal.